# Two scrollable column design with fixed titles

Tags: css, scroll, positioning, multiple-columns

I am trying to make two separately scrollable columns
as in this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r86ME/1/), where the first column is already scrollable.

However, in the second column I need only part of the column to be scrollable with Title to stay as the rest is scrolled away.

Here is the code I am trying:

```
<div class="col1">
    ...
</div>
<div class="col2">
    Title
    <div class="scrollable">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

and the css is

```
.col1 {
    position: fixed;
    width: 25%;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.col2 {
    position: fixed;
    left: 30%;
}
.scrollable {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Any idea how to achieve this functionality?
(With or without Bootstrap if that helps.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="sidebar">
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
<div class="header">
    <h2>Title</h2>
</div>
<div class="scrollable">
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
    <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sidebar {
    position: fixed;
    width: 25%;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.header {
    position: fixed;
    left: 35%;
}  
.scrollable {
    position: fixed;
    width: 25%;
    left: 35%;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 70px;
    bottom: 0;
}
```